# Persist data for different users redux-persist

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, local-storage, redux-persist

There is a question, how can I **persist data for different users**? In my case I have chat app, for example when user logs out, his data is saved in a local storage with the help of redux-persist. But when he logs in a different account, he should get data for that account, not data that is in localstorage for old account.So the question is how to manage that flow and is it possible with redux-persist? Something like store data in localstorage by key(id of user) and value(persisted state for that user) for example.

Comment: That is when you need a database :) Or you can work around and keep some information inside the `user token` and decode it in runtime, but it won't be practical

Comment: And what database I could take for this puproses? And may be some samples of how it should look with redux-persist implementation?